# Cleanup after the background process finished its work on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script-launcher (bash) that executes Python scripts in the background, so I can start it and then close terminal/ssh connection, leaving the script working.

It accepts the name of the script to run and optional arguments to pass there. Then it starts the Python script (detached) and creates a file with PID (of the Python script) in the same directory, so I can later reconnect to the server and kill this background process by using the PID from this file.

Also this PID file is used to prevent the same script been started if it's already running (singleton).

The problem is that I can't figure out how to delete this PID file after the Python script finished its work. I need this to be implemented in bash script, no Python solutions (since I want to use it for all cases) or **screen** tool. This supervisor (that will delete PID file after the script finished work) also should be run in the background (!), so I can do the same thing: close terminal session.

What I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDFILE=$1.pid

if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
    echo "Process is already running, PID: $(< $PIDFILE)"
    exit 1
else
    nohup python $1 "${@:2}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    PID=$!
    echo $PID > $PIDFILE
    # supervisor
    nohup sh -c "wait $PID; rm -f $PIDFILE" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

In this example the PID file is deleted immediately, because **wait** command returns immediately (I think it's because the new process isn't a child of the current one, so **wait** doesn't work in this case as I expect).

Do you have any thoughts about how it can be implemented?
Basically, I need something to replace this line

```
nohup sh -c "wait $PID; rm -f $PIDFILE" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

that will wait until the previous script (Python's in this case) will finish its work and then delete PID file.

UPD: OK, the problem was with **wait** command, because it can't wait for non-child processes. The working solution is to replace it with **while** loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

function cleanup {
    while [ -e /proc/$1 ]; do
        sleep 1;
    done
    rm -f $PIDFILE
}

PIDFILE=$1.pid

if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
    echo "Process is already running, PID: $(< $PIDFILE)"
    exit 1
else
    python $1 "${@:2}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    PID=$!
    echo $PID > $PIDFILE
    cleanup $PID > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    disown
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For shell scripts, use [traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
function finish {
    wait $PID
    rm $PIDFILE > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}

trap finish            EXIT
trap "finish; exit 2"  SIGINT

PIDFILE=$1.pid

if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
    echo "Process is already running, PID: $(< $PIDFILE)"
    exit 1
else
    nohup python $1 "${@:2}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    PID=$!
    echo $PID > $PIDFILE
fi
```

Traps allow you to catch [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) and respond to them, so in the code above, the *EXIT* signal (normal completion) will execute finish, removing the `$PIDFILE`. On *SIGINT* (user requested exit with ctrl-c), the script will remove the `$PIDFILE` and exit with 2.

Directly in python: if you want to handle it manually take a look at [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html). I haven't looked at the source, but it looks like it implements [traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(computing)) in order to register cleanup functions:

```
import atexit
import os


def cleanup():
    os.unlink(pidfile)


atexit.register(cleanup)
```

Or to automate pidfile handling checkout [pid](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pid/) which will handle preventing simultaneous execution all on its own:

```
from pid import PidFile

with PidFile():
  do_something()
```

or better yet

```
from pid.decorator import pidfile

@pidfile()
def main():
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: This solution is locked to Python, but I'll run not only Python scripts, so I need something implemented in Bash

Comment: Ah, apologies, one moment.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it blocks until the Python script finished its work. I need this supervisor to work in the background as well, so this script-launcher should finish its work almost immediately (start Python script, start supervisor, exit).

Comment: That's not a problem with this code, that's something you would need to implement separately. You could use `subprocess.Popen(["/bin/mycmd", "myarg"]).pid` to allow you to initiate a background process. All you need to do is apply that within the method called by atexit, or the primary operations in your case.

Comment: For bash, all you would need to do is background the wrapper, but this really sounds like something you should be handling in the primary script. If you're using supervisor, you could just set numprocs to 1 and call it a day, there's no need to manage this manually.

Comment: could you explain why `exit 2` is before `finish` ?

Comment: I answered this a long time ago, but that looks incorrect to me now too. I'm gonna update and put finish first.